# Sincronização SQLite e MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Tenho um aplicação no qual possuo um banco de dados usando SQLite e um serviço externo utilizando MySQL. Basicamente é uma aplicação de tarefas, no qual que posso criar uma tarefa em modo *offline*. Quando o usuário possuir internet ele já automaticamente enviar para o MySQL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho que fazer o tratamento de sincronização e não estou conseguindo resolver isso.

**USER 1**

- Criar uma tarefa
- Sicronizar a tarefa com banco externo

**USER 2**

- Verificar se há tarefas no banco externo
- Sincronizar tarefas

### Problema

Após o usuário 2 (USER 2) concluir sua tarefa, ele deve fazer a sincronia novamente com o MySQL, e sucessivamente o usuário 1 (USER 1) tem que receber também essa atualização na sua base dados.

Da forma mais simplificada possível, as tabelas seriam:

#### tbl_task no SQLite

- id_interno-----------( identificador unico para controle interno)
- nome_tarefa----------( nome da tarefa )
- status---------------( status de realização da tarefa pendente/feito)
- id_usuario-----------( usuario que realizará a tarefa )
- id_autor-------------( usuario criador da tarefa )
- id_externo-----------( identificador externo caso ja tenha sicronizado )

#### tbl_task no MySQL

- id-------------------( identificador unico )
- nome_tarefa----------( nome da tarefa a realizar )
- status---------------( status de realização da tarefa pendente/feito)
- id_usuario-----------( usuario que realizará a tarefa )
- id_autor-------------( usuario criador da tarefa )

A minha ideia inicial seria criar uma coluna na tabela com o nome `SYNC`, no qual eu teria controle se foi sincronizado ou não. Porém após o **USER 2** concluir uma tarefa, como o **USER 1** verificará essa conclusão?

Comment: Ao invés de gravar apenas um campo SYNC, por que vc não usa também um campo de **ultima_atualizacao** do tipo _TIMESTAMP_ ? Dessa maneira, quando o usuário atualizar os dados da tarefa, ele salva esses dados no banco. Assim, ao realizar a sincronia dos dados, se a tarefa armazenada localmente tiver um TIMESTAMP menor que o do banco externo, é por que ela está desatualizada, portanto, precisa ser sincronizada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma tarefa agendada no App para realizar a consulta na base e verificar se existem novos usuários.

Existem dois conceitos aqui, um em que todos consultam o servidor para saber se houve atualização dos dados e um segundo em que o servidor é quem notifica a todos que os dados foram atualizados. 
Ambos os conceitos tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, sendo que o primeiro é mais fácil de ser aplicado e o segundo traz mais performance para a aplicação. Veja por exemplo o [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) e o [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br).